# What formula to chose a nonlinear formula?

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a formula

$$f(x) = x,$$

where $0 \leq x \leq 255$

Now I want to have a formula

$$f(x) = y,$$

where $0 \leq x \leq 255$, where $f(0) = 0$, $f(255) = 255$ and e.g., $f(128) = 150$ (the value of $150$ might vary).

All other values should be interpolated.

So actually I want a function that is nonlinear (starts with $0$ and goes up to $255$, starting increasing fast and finishes increasing slow); opposite as a parabolic function.

What (kind of) function should I use?

Comment: So you want a function $f(x)$ such that  $f(0) = 0$ , $f(128)=150$ and  $f(255) = 255$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You may use a logistic function.

Comment: You can interpolate and get a parabolic function, I don't get what you mean by "opposite as a parabolic function".

Comment: @NoChance indeed, and in between values interpolated (like a smooth curve)

Comment: @Crostul a parabolic f(x) = x ^2 starts increasing slow, and increases faster with higher x values, I want opposite (faster start, slower end)

Comment: @minoriminus I think so ... but how can I find easily a logarithmic function that has f(0) = 0, f(128) = 150 and f(255)=255 ... I'm not sure of the 150, so it would be nice if I have a formula that has 150 in it's right hand side.

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+((0,0),(128,150)(255,255)) . Wolfram Alpha describes an arc of a parabola.

Comment: @Crostul thanks ... this is exactly what I need (if you make it an answer I can upvote/accept it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WA gives $$\frac{10933x-11x^2}{8128}$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+((0,0),(128,150)(255,255))

Answer (score 6):

I think one classical example of nonlinearity could be the gamma for color correction.

[image]

Instead of using the interval $X=0\ ..\ 255$ it is easier to work in $[0,1]$ by scaling $x=\frac X{255}$.

Now, remark that any $x^\gamma$ stays in $[0,1]$ since $0^\gamma=0$ and $1^\gamma=1$.

Remark: *this is not exactly color correction, which is $x^{1/\gamma}$, but this is just a convention*.

So you have linearity for $\gamma=1$ and non-linearity for any other value of the exponent.

Note that if you really want to work with bytes the result can be scaled back using $255\times\left(\frac X{255}\right)^\gamma$

Depending of your choice of $\gamma<1$ or $\gamma>1$ you will get either a fast increase at the start of the interval or at the end of the interval.

Try it here (move the g cursor): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cnc2diykyx

Comment: Actually, this is indeed exact the reason I use it for ... but I kind of promised the acceptance of the answer to Crostul (since he exactly answered my question), but your answer is perfect for the reason I need it for. Hope you understand.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers In that case, I'd wager there already exists a library function for precisely that purpose

Comment: Desmos seems like an excellent tool. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Probably yes, but for this so simple function I can program the one line formula.

Answer (score 2):

To satisfy the requirements:
$$f(128)=150, f(255)=255$$

However, $f(0)=0$ can't be satisfied by this method. I assumed that f(1)=1, however 
you can change the numbers but not use zero, otherwise, there would be no inverse.

[image]

An example of the curve looks like this [Curve](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4podzayav6)

I can provide more info about the derivation if you want.

Comment: Thanks ... Crostul gave me already a satisfactory formula, but good to know it can be derived too... I'm not fully understand the derivation, but for me it's not that needed right know... I always can search on internet how to solve matrix calculations (I had them at school long time ago, but forgotten about them meanwhile).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You can construct an equation of the form $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ and substitute 3 non-zero values you know x and y for. You will get a system of equations having 3 unknowns (A, B, C). You solve for theses unknowns and plug the values back into $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$. Matrix calculations are optional.

Comment: Thanks ... that makes a lot of sense indeed, thanks for that info (very useful if in future I encounter similar problems, solving such equations even I should still be able to do that :-)  ).

Comment: Thank you, I will be very happy to help.

Comment: Thanks (although most of my questions are in the electronics/Arduino stack exchange).